# docker load balancing on two different server

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is it possible to have docker installed on two servers and then using azure DevOps server, deploy the `asp.net core Publish` to the both servers?

If yes, I think, I need to have local registry on both servers. Then using docker-compose push the images to servers.

Am I right?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is the use case of having docker registry on both servers?

Comment: if I have two containers of an image on the same server, when the server downs, all my containers will be down too. I think the containers should be on the different servers. ha ?

Comment: Containers should be on different servers. Docker registry is different, right? The place where we keep the docker images 'roughly' a local version of docker hub.

Comment: So I want everything be on my own registries. Not online. Then Should I have a registry and two servers with docker installed. Then Run the image as a container on both servers to be able to have load balancing. Am I right?